# magento 1.9 not redirecting customer to success page after a successful order

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, checkoutsession

I’m facing a strange problem I’m working on magento 1.9.
Sometimes after a success order the customer is not redirected to success page, this happens not in all orders maybe 1 of 5.
after diagnosing the issue I found out that in

```
core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
```

it seems that there’s no  getLastSuccessQuoteId() as showen in the pictures bellow

I was thinking that it may be happen because of redis but i’m not sure. does anyone faced some similar problem before or have an idea on how can I solve this issue ? Thank you :)
Screenshot 2020-03-31 at 22.05.47.png

[**strong text**[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6PoF.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your
app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnePageController.php

go to saveOrderAction function and 
after  $this->getOnepage()->saveOrder(); line
add your redirect url

```
$redirectUrl = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout()->getRedirectUrl();
```

at the end of code add below code:

```
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->save();

    if (isset($redirectUrl)) {
        $result['redirect'] = $redirectUrl;
    }
```